# Upgrading from Windows 8 to 8.1 RTM on a Boot Camp partition

Tags: bootcamp, upgrade, windows

Have anyone been able to upgrade/install Windows 8.1 on a Boot Camp partition?
When trying to upgrade to 8.1 RTM it goes into blue screen on first boot, claiming that "A required device is missing" and then rolls back the update:

[image: BSOD Error]

This is the error message I get after rollback:

```
0x101 - 0x20017
```

UPDATE: When upgrading via the Windows Store, I get this error message after rollback:

```
0xC1900101 - 0x20017
```

Comment: Do you install from a DVD, app, usb? and did you check install the updates?
I'm about myself to try, read elsehwere some got same as you but worked when they ran with DVD (burned iso) and only sounds came out strange.

Comment: I installed from USB, checked to install updates. 
But I have only tried starting the upgrade from Windows, not from boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by reinstalling Windows 8.1 on the Bootcamp partition and the re-added it to Parallels.

The suggestions from @foregon and @Nash were helpful, but unfortunately had no effect on my system.

Answer (score 4):

I am very happy to report, that, at least with 2012 15" Retina Macbook Pros (and I think a good chance with all other relevant Mac models), that there is a method to upgrade Windows 8 to 8.1 (even Enterprise, in my case) without the need for a DVD or USB drive.

You simply mount the ISO and run the setup file from the mounted disc, while following the steps I lay out below (and actually, I think that even just extracting the files from your MSDN ISO (or running the update from the Windows Store), would work as well!):

(Again, I have a 2012 15" Retina Macbook Pro, currently with OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion), Bootcamp 5.0 (no rEFIt, just simple bootcamp setup), and until 30 minutes ago, Windows 8 x64 Enterprise EN-US.)

- First preparation step, is to make sure, in both Win 8's Bootcamp Control Panel settings AND Mountain Lion's System Preferences, to set the Windows partition as the default boot drive. I checked thoroughly on both sides and rebooted a couple times to make sure Windows was what it would ALWAYS boot to no matter what I chose (via alt key) the last time.
- To make sure you can do a seamless 'in-place' upgrade, keeping your ['Windows settings, personal files and apps'](http://www.knappett.net/itblog/?p=66), you need to make sure the 'target language' of your 8.1 ISO is the same as your Windows 8's 'host language', so if you have an EN-GB Windows 8 you should download the EN-GB 8.1 ISO if you want to do a full in-place upgrade instead of a clean or half-way reinstall. (However it may be possible to just change to EN-US from EN-GB by carefully changing ALL system language and regional and keyboard settings to EN-US and deleting all instances of EN-GB temporarily to make it a match - I cannot confirm this though.)
- Simply mount your ISO and run its setup.exe to start the install process. To mount natively in Windows 8, right-click on ISO in Windows Explorer and 'Mount' is at the top of the context menu. If it is not, follow [this](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/12394-how-to-re-enable-iso-mounting-in-windows-8-file-explorer) guide to temporarily make the option visible in Windows Explorer.
- The install process will take you through the upgrade, painlessly through about 5-6 reboots, and each time, because it has been carefully set and checked (on  both sides of Bootcamp) to ALWAYS boot into Windows partition by default, you are secure in Windows properly continuing through the install process every time. (I have installed Windows from extracted ISO folder on C drive before, so even non-mounting may work in this instance as well.)

Done.

Comment: Thanks! After reading this, I successfully upgraded to Windows 8.1. I had to disable the NVIDIA High Definition Audio driver to make my system stable. I blogged about it here: http://blog.ctaggart.com/2013/12/windows-81-on-boot-camp-5-on-macbook-pro.html

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has issues, I had exactly this blue screen issue, and just managed to get the app store update working using Parallels. The ISO method didn't work for me as my Windows 7 to Windows 8 upgrade key didn't get recognised.

So for me, this worked:

1. Download Parallels (trial should also do it).
2. Load Windows 8 on your bootcamp partition into Parallels. Parallels will do a bunch of stuff to get the bootcamp partition to behave like a VM (you can still login directly into your bootcamp instance).
3. While in Parallels, Go to Windows Store and get the Windows update.
4. Let the updates complete and let the Parallels instance restart itself.
5. During the reboot, Parallels may complain about OS X preventing Windows from messing with the boot partition. Just hit OK, and proceed. It'll also warn you that you may have issues booting into the bootcamp partition without Parallels (doesn't seem to be a problem).
6. After the upgrade completes, shutdown the Parallels instance cleanly and reboot your Mac into your bootcamp partition.
7. If all goes well, you should see the driver update spinner, and after a while, it should go to the new setup steps.

Comment: Tried the exact steps in the post above, but step 5 never happened. Same blue screen as the screenshot in the first post.

Comment: Ahh, dang - so you got the same error even in parallels?  Sorry to hear it :( The steps above worked on a current model 15" retina macbook pro. I haven't tried on any earlier models.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to win 8.1 from windows store. Boot camp 4 allows 8.1 to run in partition but no longer allows Boot camp to run - thus losing some driver functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Apple know issue.

Now with Mac OS X 10.8.5, Boot Camp had an upgrade, so it's compatible with Windows 8.1.

If it still not working, try to reinstall Windows 8.1 RTM from the Boot Camp app, or install it booting from Windows 8.1 RTM DVD into Boot Camp partition.

Comment: I have 10.8.5 installed, but I'd really like to just do an upgrade instead of a complete reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was crazy enough to just try the upgrade within Windows 8.0 on boot camp (updated OS to 10.8.5). Ran from DVD and got option to upgrade and keep settings files and Apps.... apps? applications or only win8 apps??? got little scared but reading it do keep application.

Ran with success! :) now in Win 8.1 it just want me to repair my VPN client, so so far it looks great! it works (for me at least)

Comment: So DVD works but USB does not?

Comment: Well I didn't try USB so cannot tell for sure. I burned an ISO to DVD and ran it from there. Read you can mount the ISO and run it without a physical DVD drive but I did the old school and it worked for me. Seems it is driver/device based also if it works, I'm on a Mac BookPro and it worked just fine there.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully upgraded my Windows 8 Boot Camp to 8.1 today via a combination of the marketplace download and 8.1 ISO DVD. I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro with Boot Camp 5 and this was my method:

1. [Burn the 8.1 ISO image to DVD](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-tip-download-windows-81-iso-windows-8-product-key).
2. Change startup disk to Boot Camp partition in either OS X or via Boot Camp control panel in Windows & reboot into Windows if not already there.
3. Insert 8.1 ISO DVD into the superdrive - if you don't have a drive, get hold of an external one (this disk MUST be in drive at the point Windows 8 has downloaded from the marketplace).
4. Download and Perform the 8.1 upgrade from the store (it will reboot 3-4 times doing the upgrade, plus you should hear the DVD being accessed post auto reboots).
5. Test your newly upgraded Windows, then use the Boot Camp control panel to switch your default boot drive back to OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my 8.1 without a second thought and no real issues except when i bootup with a thunderbolt display the resolution is off till i restart a few times.  Turns out the 6700 HD AMD graphics card windows 8 driver doesn't play nice with 8.1.  Very annoying but no problems and I am running maverick on late model 2011 MBP 17" 16gb ram upgrade and 1 TB SSD drive upgrade. Runs beautifully otherwise. I haven't tried gaming since the upgrade to 8.1 so we'll see.

I had windows 8 already installed through bootcamp when i was on mtn OS lion, pretty sure i upgraded to 8.1 after the mavericks download.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this by installing a fresh efi windows 8.1 install first (no bootcamp assistant !!FRESH!!), and then install bootcamp for drivers after first login. 
If you want to add new acc, u should uninstall bootcamp software after u got all drivers working like wifi etc.. Or else, you will receive bluescreen AGAIN. 
I am not sure why install windows or add an account with bootcamp cause this error, but just follow my direction and it works..